# Issue with connected-react-router

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I have created the following routes using connected-react-router as shown below

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/a" component={A}/>
    <Route exact={true} path="/b" component={B}/>
    <Route path="/c/:id" component={C}/>
</Switch>
```

But when I hit the url my.domain.com/c, the component does not get render. But when I go and give the url my.domain.com/c/12, then it works. I have tried setting exact={false} as well. Still it does not work. Any help will help me proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the route:

```
<Route path="/c/:id" component={C}/>
```

You are saying that the "id" it's mandatory. If you need render the page even if the user don't pass the id, you need to add "?":

```
<Route path="/c/:id?" component={C}/>
```